# Linux RHEL c++ socket server Bind error and SO_REUSEADDR error

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, port, serversocket

At the beginning, I had problems Binding my server.
I thought it was because the port(?) was still in use by a dangling process.

So I added :

```
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *) &yes, sizeof(yes)) == -1) {
    cout << "**[ Server ] -> [ ERROR on socket options ]" << endl;
}
```

to reuse my port.
however, this didn't make a change.

Still giving me a binding error & setsocketopt error.

here are My variables :

```
struct ifaddrs * ifAddrStruct;
struct ifaddrs * ifa;
void * tmpAddrPtr;
char ADDR_IPv4[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
int sockfd, newsockfd;
socklen_t clilent;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

ifAddrStruct=NULL;
ifa=NULL;
tmpAddrPtr=NULL;
```

here is my code with the problem

```
bool VMS_alarmServer::Initialize_Alarm_Server(){

    this->getIPv4();
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    if(socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0){
        cout << "**[ Server ] -> [ ERROR opening socket ]" << endl;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ADDR_IPv4);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(sPORT);

    int yes = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *) &yes, sizeof(yes)) == -1) {
        cout << "**[ Server ] -> [ ERROR on socket options ]" << endl;
    }
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        cout << "**[ Server ] -> [ ERROR on binding ]" << endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What's the actual error that you are getting? Update your question. Make sure there's no other process binding that port already.